# How to generate addresses for a rudimentary BTC transfer app

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, development, coinbase.com

I am a student studying web development at a prominent bootcamp in the United States. For my capstone project, I have decided to try and build a fairly simple application wherein one authenticated user can send an amount of BTC to another user (I described to my teacher as a bottled tipping platform). To do this, I am using the Coinbase API. While this sounds simple in theory, there are many points at which I am worried about tripping up.

Conceptually, I have been facing a dilemma about how the user's wallet will interact with the app. My initial impulse was to have the user plug in an external wallet when they created their account. In order to transfer from one user to another, the payer would send payments to a central wallet (for which I set up an OAUTH2 application), which would in turn send the coin to the payee. Under this paradigm, the technical messiness of actually creating the wallet could be avoided and the focus could be on the actual transfer of BTC. As I read the documentation, however, I lost confidence in the feasibility of my approach. Specifically, I was unsure of how I would go about generating addresses from both the payer and payee, a core part of the transfer process. Is my conceptual approach even possible? If it is, how would I go about getting the addresses from the payer/payee and pass them to the central wallet?